# Adding data to DataGridView Column wise

Tags: winforms, datagrid, datagridview, runtime

I want to add data in Data Grid View column wise.

I am adding the column at runtime and then i want to add data to it.

Also is it possible that the columns resize themselves to fit the window.

eg-If there are 10 columns then 10 columns should fill the window else if there are 5 columns then 5 columns should fill the window

Comment: Do you already have data in the grid when you add the new column? If so how does that data get there, is the grid unbound or bound to a datasource, and if a datasource what is the type of that?

Comment: @DavidHall  I don't have any data in the grid.The grid is empty.Now i have to add a column to it and add values to that column.The values are in a List

Comment: @DavidHall If it can be done in ListView then also it is fine.I just need to display data...Thanks in Advance

Comment: Ah ok, so you just have one list of values (strings?) that you want to display to the user, and will never have another column to display? And do you want users to be able to edit the data? And the be able to add new items. Sorry for the twenty questions but they help to know just the right control and binding method to suggest.

Comment: Actually, from the second question about scaling columns, it sounds like you list can sometimes have multiple items in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for a simple example doing what you want. It is from the code behind for a simple form with one DataGridView control on it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingList<BindingClass> data = new BindingList<BindingClass>() { 
            new BindingClass { Name = "joe", Surname = "bloggs" }, 
            new BindingClass { Name = "sue", Surname = "bloggs" } };
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    }

}   

    public class BindingClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }

}
```

I've created a custom object to use for my data - this is where your list goes. All the public properties of lists bound to the DataGridView's datasource get created as columns - you can then hide unwanted columns.

In my example I've chosen to use a `BindingList<T>` rather than a `List<T>` - this is generally preferred since it gives you editing and can be extended to support sorting.

I also set the `AutoSizeColumnsMode` of the grid to `Fill` - there are several other options including setting the width or fill properties of each column individually, and these can also be set through the designer.

---

I don't recommend using a `ListView` since it doesn't offer automatic databinding.